# Android - waiting for json to get value before continuing with method

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I am using [this](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) library in order to get data from server. The data is decode in the server into `JSONObject`. The method I made will call the url and return the number of rows inside a `mysql` table.

The method is working however, I cannot return the value properly from my method:

ParseLevels.java

```
static public int countLevels() {

        final int[] count = {0};
        AndroidNetworking.get("https://example.com/gameLevels.php?option=count")
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // responce is {count:20}
                        try {
                            count[0] = response.getInt("count"); // this is getting the value of 20
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Log.d("responce_app", String.valueOf(count[0]));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        // handle error
                        Log.d("responce_app", String.valueOf(error)); //Logs out 20
                    }
                });

        return count[0]; // return always 0
    }
```

When I call from my `MainActivity` 
`Log.d("responce_app", String.valueOf(ParseLevels.countLevels()));`
the method returns always 0.

I understand that the return is fired before the `jsonObject` is fetched however, how can I wait for the method to fetch the `jsonObject` and after return the value?

In iOS I use something like:

```
static func getLevels(feedsArray: (levelsCount : [Int]) -> Void) {


}
```

how could convert this into Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I wait for the method to fetch the jsonObject and after return
>   the value?

Two options:

**1.** Do code inside `onResponse` method which want to execute according to result of request.

**2.** Create  event listener using `interface` and implement it in `countLevels` method caller class to execute block of code when `onResponse`  method execution done

Comment: Thanks. I have Created event listener using interface: `public interface CountLevelCallback{
        void afterCount(int count);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the the `Making Synchronous Request` example from your library's README:
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

```
ANRequest request = AndroidNetworking.get("https://fierce-cove-29863.herokuapp.com/getAllUsers/{pageNumber}")
                    .addPathParameter("pageNumber", "0")
                    .addQueryParameter("limit", "3")
                    .build();
ANResponse<List<User>> response = request.executeForParsed(new TypeToken<List<User>>() {});
if (response.isSuccess()) {
    List<User> users = responseTwo.getResult();
} else {
    //handle error
}
```

You would return your count in the `response.isSuccess()` conditional.

Comment: I have already tried this however, I get error `Cannot resolve method 'isSuccess()`